# awk to search field in file2 using range of file1

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to find all the `$2` values in `file2` which is `~30MB`, that are between `$2` and `$3` in `file1` which is ~2GB. If a value in `$2` of `file2` is between the `file1` fields then it is printed along with the `$6` value in `file1`. Both `file1` and `file2` are `tab-delimited` as well as the `desired output`. If there is nothing to print then the next line is processed. The `awk` below runs but is very slow (has been processing for ~ 1 day and still not done). Is there a better way to approach this or a better programming language?

`$1` and `$2` and `$3` from `file1` and `$1` and `$2` of `file2` must match `$1` of `file1` and be in the range of `$2` and `$3` of `file1`.

so in order for the line to be printed in the output it must match `$1` and be in the range of `$2` and `$3` of `file2`

So, since the line from `file2`matches `$1` in `file1` and in the `$2` and `$3` range it is printed in the output.
Thank you :).

**file1** (~3MB)

```
 1  948953  948956  chr1:948953-948956  .   ISG15
 1  949363  949858  chr1:949363-949858  .   ISG15
 2  800000  900500  chr1:800000-900500  .   AGRN
```

**file2** (~80MB)

```
 1  12214   .   C   G
 1  949800  .   T   G
 2  900000  rs123   -   A
 3  900000  .   C   -
```

**desired output** `tab-delimited`

```
1   949800  .   T   G     ISG15
2   900000  rs123   -   A   AGRN
```

**awk**

```
 awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '                   
NR == FNR {min[NR]=$2; max[NR]=$3; Gene[NR]=$NF; next}
 {                
     for (id in min) 
         if (min[id] < $2 && $2 < max[id]) {
             print $0, id, Gene[id]
             break              
         }
}                                     
' file1 file2
```

Comment: I edited the post hopefully it helps.  Thank you :).

Comment: is `2   900000  rs123   -   A` or `2   900000  rs123   -   A   AGRN` in desired output?

Comment: Sorry thats correct: `2 900000 rs123 - A AGRN`.  Made the change in the post as well. Thank you :).

Comment: In case you should test some or all of these solutions, I'd be interested in hearing their execution times?

Comment: I will test them and report back the execution times when I get a chance (end of the year is always a busy time).  But i will definitely test all these great solutions.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be faster than what you have since it only loops through the file1 contents that have the same $1 value as in file2 and stops searching after it finds a range that matches:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    c = ++num[$1]
    beg[$1][c] = $2
    end[$1][c] = $3
    val[$1][c] = $NF
    next
}
$1 in val {
    for (c=1; c<=num[$1]; c++) {
        if ( (beg[$1][c] <= $2) && ($2 <= end[$1][c]) ) {
            print $0, val[$1][c]
            break
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
1       949800  .       T       G       ISG15
2       900000  rs123   -       A       AGRN
```

Unfortunately for unsorted input as you have there's not too many options to make it faster. If the ranges in file1 can overlap each other then remove the "break".

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$0;B[$1,++D[$1]]=$2;next} {++C[$1]}($2<B[$1,C[$1]] && $3>B[$1,C[$1]]){print A[$1]}'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

Reading the files one by one here, first reading file Input_file2 and then Input_file1 here.

Answer (score 1):

It may be ineffective but should work, however slowly:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$2]=$0; next }
              { for(i in a) 
                    if(i>=$2 && i<=$3) print a[i] "\t" $6 }
  ' f2 f1
1       949800  .       T       G       ISG15
3       900000  .       C       -       AGRN
```

Basically it reads the `file2`in memory and for every line in `file1` it goes thru every entry of `file2` (in memory). It won't read a 2 GB file into memory so it's still got less looking up to do as your version.

You could speed it up by replacing the `print a[i] "\t" $6` with `{print a[i] "\t" $6; delete a[i]}`.

**EDIT**: Added tab delimited to output and refreshed the output to reflect the changed data. Printing `"\t"` is enough as the files are already tab delimited and records do not get rebuilt at any point.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to use AWK to generate another AWK file. Memory consumption should be low so for a *really* big `file1` this might be a lifesaver. As for speed, that might depend on how smart the AWK implementation is. I haven't had a chance to try it on huge data sets; I am curious about your findings.

Create a file `step1.awk`:

```
{
    sub(/^chr/, "", $1);
    print "$1==\"" $1 "\" && " $2 "<$2 && $2<" $3 " { print $0 \"\\t" $6 "\"; }";
}
```

Apply that on `file1`:

```
$ awk -f step1.awk file1
$1=="1" && 948953<$2 && $2<948956 { print $0 "\tISG15"; }
$1=="1" && 949363<$2 && $2<949858 { print $0 "\tISG15"; }
```

Pipe the output to a file `step2.awk` and apply that on `file2`:

```
$ awk -f step1.awk file1 > step2.awk
$ awk -f step2.awk file2
 1  949800  rs201725126 T   G   ISG15
```

### Alternative: generating C

I rewrote `step1.awk`, making it generate C rather than AWK code. Not only will this solve the memory issue you reported earlier; it will also be a *lot* faster considering the fact that C is compiled to native code.

```
BEGIN {
    print "#include <stdio.h>";
    print "#include <string.h>";
    print "int main() {";
    print "   char s[999];";
    print "   int a, b;";
    print "   while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin)) {";
    print "      s[strlen(s)-1] = 0;";
    print "      sscanf(s, \"%d %d\", &a, &b);";
}

{
    print "      if (a==" $1 " && " $2 "<b && b<" $3 ") printf(\"%s\\t%s\\n\", s, \"" $6 "\");";
}

END {
    print "   }";
    print "}";
}
```

Given your sample `file1`, this will generate the following C source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
   char s[999];
   int a, b;
   while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin)) {
      s[strlen(s)-1] = 0;
      sscanf(s, "%d %d", &a, &b);
      if (a==1 && 948953<b && b<948956) printf("%s\t%s\n", s, "ISG15");
      if (a==1 && 949363<b && b<949858) printf("%s\t%s\n", s, "ISG15");
      if (a==2 && 800000<b && b<900500) printf("%s\t%s\n", s, "AGRN");
   }
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ awk -f step1.awk file1 > step2.c
$ cc step2.c -o step2
$ ./step2 < file2
 1  949800  .   T   G   ISG15
 2  900000  rs123   -   A   AGRN
```

Comment: I added an edit as one additional field is needed but I am not sure how to incorporate it.  Thank you :).

Comment: I get the error below:
`awk: awkgram.y:5015: find_line: Assertion `lineno > 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)` and will post more details in the post.  Thank you very much :).

Comment: @Chris Considering the severity of the error it might be that AWK ran out of memory. My optimism on memory consumption was wrong; I think AWK will store the entire (parsed) contents of `step2.awk` in memory.

Comment: @Ruud well, yeah, awk has to read the contents of the script file `step2.awk` to be able to execute it so if that's enormous then it could cause problems.

Comment: @Chris I rewrote the script to generate C rather than AWK. That should solve the memory issue **and** give an enormous performance boost.

Comment: @Ruud , thank you very much, I am have not too familiar with C but many of the tools I use are written in C and my co-worker likes it immensely. I will try it out and let you know how it goes.... thank you very much for all your help :).

Answer (score 1):

If the performance is the issue, you have to sort both files by the value (and range start).

With the files sorted your scans can be incremental (and consequently much faster)

Here is an untested script

```
$ awk '{line=$0; k=$2;   
        getline < "file1"; 
        while (k >= $2) getline < "file1"; 
        if(k <= $3) print line, $NF}' file2
```

Comment: That will go into an infinite loop given a getline failure, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for how to call getline safely.

Comment: Thank you all for the great solutions,  explanations, and help. I really appreciate it as my datasets are only getting larger.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a dict from `file1` using multiarrays in `gawk`, this is more efficient computational (`file1` has small size compared to `file2`),

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{for(i=$2;i<=$3;++i) d[$1,i] = $6; next}
    d[$1,$2]{print $0, d[$1,$2]}' file1 file2
```

you get,

```
1  949800  .   T   G ISG15
2  900000  rs123   -   A AGRN
```